Is $\int_D \nabla f dx = 0$ for $f$ compactly supported?
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and $f$ a smooth compactly supported function such that its support is contained within $D$. I am interested in
$$\int_D \nabla f dx.$$
If $n = 1$, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus it is obvious that this integral is zero. However I am less sure when $n > 1$. Is the integral still equal to zero? If so, how can one see this?

It is a vector, simply integrate each of the components just like the $1$D case

@NinadMunshi For the $i$th component wouldn't we have something like $\int \partial_{x_i} f dx$? So we cannot use the FTC since the integral is over $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and is not something like $\int \partial_{x_i} f dx_i$.

You are free to choose the order of integration. What happens if you integrate $dx_i$ first and your innermost boundaries are level sets that lie on the "edges" of $D$ and outside your region of compact support?

@NinadMunshi Ah yes that was very stupid of me, thanks for the help!

The final answer is more complex than this simple case since $D$ is not guaranteed to be convex (for example imagine an S shape and your region of compact support is embedded in a weird way) but I will allow you to work out the details of what happens when you carve up $D$ and glue the boundary terms together on your own.

You can modify the divergence theorem to obtain $$\int_{\Omega}\nabla f~\mathrm d\mu^m=\int_{\partial\Omega}fn~\mathrm d\mu^{m-1}$$

If you know about differential forms, this is immediate from Stokes’s Theorem.  Consider, for example, $\omega=f\,dx_2\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$. Then $$\int_D \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n = \int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D}\omega=0.$$
(By the way, you mean to say that the support of $f$ is contained in the interior of $D$.)

Let $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. Then since $f = 0$ off $D$,
\begin{align}
\int_D f_{x_j}(x)\,dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_{x_j}(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{x_j}(x',x_j)\,dx_j\,dx' \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}}\int_{-M}^{M}f_{x_j}(x', x_j)\,dx_j\,dx' \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}}(f(x', M) - f(x', -M))\,dx'.
\end{align}
This holds for $M$ such that $|x_j| < M$ for all $x \in D$. Such $M$ exists because $D$ is bounded. Of course, $f(x', M) = f(x', -M) = 0$, so the integral is $0$.
